# How to avoid/eliminate Integrity error on form fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form that displays details but when I bring in a filter it fails. Where is the mistake??
The error is here

```
File "C:\Users\FR GULIK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: libman_issue.book_id_id
```

This is the form

```
class IssueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IssueForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['book_id'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Books.objects.filter(no_of_books=1),label='Available books')
    class Meta:
        model = Issue
        fields = ['borrower_id',]
```

When I have the form as shown below it works.

```
class IssueForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
        model = Issue
        fields = ['borrower_id','book_id']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the 'book_id' to the `fields`

```
class IssueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IssueForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['book_id'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Books.objects.filter(no_of_books=1),label='Available books')
    class Meta:
        model = Issue
        fields = ['borrower_id','book_id']
```